# How to get the output in html from json using Rapidapi?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I've been trying hard to get the output in HTML table from the **Json** file and the API I used from rapidapi, but I'm not getting any output and no error for code. Is there any mistake?
Anyone please help!!!

```
$.getJSON(settings).done(function(response){ 
console.log(response) });
```

This gives log to console..but other thing doesn't..why? I have been trying to get output for 2 days, but failed.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Title </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "rapidapi_url",
            "method": "GET",
            "headers" :{
                "x-rapidapi-host": "API_url",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "my_api_key"
            }
        };
        $.getJSON(settings, function(data){
            $.each(data.country_stats, function(i, f){
            console.log(i);
            console.log(f);

                var tblrw = "<tr>" + "<td>" + value.country_name + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.cases + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.deaths + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.region + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.total_recovered + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.new_deaths + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.new_cases + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.serious_critical + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.total_cases_per_1m_population + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                $(tblrw).appendTo("#tablerw tbody");

            }); 
        });

        var tblrw = "<tr>" + "<td>" + value.country_name + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.cases + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.deaths + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.region + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.total_recovered + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.new_deaths + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.new_cases + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.serious_critical + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.total_cases_per_1m_population + "</td>" + "</tr>";
        $(tblrw).appendTo("#tablerw tbody");   
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tablerw">
<thead>
<th>Country name</th>
<th>cases</th>
<th>Deaths</th>
<th>Region</th>
<th>Total Recovered</th>
<th>New Deaths</th>
<th>New cases</th>
<th>Serious/Critical</th>
<th>Total cases per 1m</th>
    </thead>
<tbody >

</tbody>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is value declared, value.country_name ???

Comment: its declared on that API in This format   ' ' ' {"countries_stat":[{"country_name":"","cases":"721","deaths":"13","region":"","total_recovered":"619","new_deaths":"0","new_cases":"0","serious_critical":"10","active_cases":"89","total_cases_per_1m_population":"0"} ' ' ' I guess this is son..and its in console

Comment: Please post $.getJSON(settings).done(function(response){ console.log(response) }); what this logs

Comment: i tried "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.country_name + "</td>" instead of value..but no error no output..please help me..

Comment: Does this variable tblrw  logs data, can you post console.log(tblrw)?

Comment: Also what does this output  console.log(f);?

Comment: console.log() gives all the data from JSON file

Comment: still not working @leo Rossetti